# Link-preview not displaying content

Tags: angular

My app tries to integrate a [link-preview](https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/link-preview/doc/index.html) into an angular app. It's basically an adaptation of the angular tour of heroes tutorial, as I am honestly very new to this.

It seems as though, the link preview recognizes the link, but the html components never generate the preview.

As per [docs](https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/link-preview/doc/index.html), I installed the dependencies and package, then imported them into the app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FriendsComponent } from './friends/friends.component';
import { FriendDetailComponent } from './friend-detail/friend-detail.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';
import { FriendSearchComponent } from './friend-search/friend-search.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatLinkPreviewModule } from '@angular-material-extensions/link-preview';
// import { StorageServiceModule } from ‘ngx-webstorage-service’;
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

The imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FriendsComponent,
    FriendDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    FriendSearchComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false },
    ),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatLinkPreviewModule.forRoot(),
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // StorageServiceModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

I then used them in this way:

```
<mat-form-field class="demo-full-width" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Enter here your text here with few links to preview ;)</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize matLinkPreview minRows="6"></textarea>
  <mat-link-preview-container [multiple]="true"></mat-link-preview-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

The rough app can be viewed [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/qnmai/the-giver).

I've been getting package warnings, and I wonder if I'm having version conflicts. The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gift-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "scss": "node-sass --watch src -o src"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-extensions/link-preview": "^1.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any online example?

Comment: @ChunbinLi yes, I have the link in my question

Comment: It would be better if you could create a link on https://stackblitz.com/ . It will help everyone to debug your code faster and get you a solution.

Comment: @amanpurohit ah okay! done: https://stackblitz.com/github/qnmai/the-giver